# How to access cookies in ExtJS which were set from aspx.cs page

Tags: extjs, cookies, extjs2

I have some aspx and some ExtJS pages in a project.

On an aspx page, cookie is set in code behind as follows

```
Response.Cookies["MYCOOKIE"].Value = "somevalue";
```

From this page user is redirected to an EXTJS page

Now on this new page, I want to get this "MYCOOKIE" value.

I tried-

```
var params = Ext.util.Cookies.get('MYCOOKIE'); // Gives error TypeError: Ext.util.Cookies is undefined
```

Any help would be appreciated

**I am using EXTJS 2.3.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer

```
document.cookie
```